# io.write won't work in nested if blocks and for loops

Tags: loops, lua, nested, output

Could someone explain me why io.write is not working when I remove the line

**io.write(inshort.."\n")** ?

There is no second definition of io.output.
Is the code too nested and io.output is invalid at some state?

I know doSomething is called correctly...

```
function findpos(arg0, arg1,argf)

    io.input(arg0)
    io.output("that.txt")
    posicounter =0
    posibuffer=""
    if not arg0 then return 99 end
    counter = 1
    while true do
        local line = io.read("*line") 
        if line == nil then break end
        for k, searchstring in ipairs(arg1) do
            found = string.find(line, searchstring)           
            if found ~=nil then 
                inshort = string.sub(line, found) 
                io.write(inshort.."\n")
                if(inshort==posibuffer) then
                posicounter=posicounter+1
                elseif posicounter >0 then
                    io.write("before")
                    node = doSomething()
                    io.write("after")
                    posicounter=0
                else 
                    posicounter=0
                    posibuffer=inshort
                end
            end
            argf(timestamp, string.sub(line, 24))       
            counter = counter +1  
        end
  end
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean here?

Comment: Also, can you please indent the code correctly.

Comment: Which Lua version is that? Are You sure `io.input(arg0)` succeeds? Could You provide source of `doSomething()`? Or it doesn't work with generic function? 

A few small notes:
1. Consider using `io.write(inshort, "\n")` instead of implicit concat.
2. Would You consider using separate file handles instead of wrapping into some shady Lua internal logics?

Comment: I'll try to have a go at these notes, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the line you are removing is the only line that outputs a `\n` character. It is likely that the problem you are seeing is that the i/o system (the operating system, or terminal, or shell) in your environment is deferring output until it sees a `\n` character. I.e., the output is line buffered.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem

Comment: As a side note, you can change the output buffering with `file:setvbuf (mode [, size])` as per [the Lua Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-file:setvbuf)